# How to zoom image by slide?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

Please suggest me, my code is given below.

```
#import "RootViewController.h"

#define ZOOM_VIEW_TAG 100
#define ZOOM_STEP 1.5


@interface RootViewController (UtilityMethods)
- (CGRect)zoomRectForScale:(float)scale withCenter:(CGPoint)center;
@end


@implementation RootViewController

@synthesize imageScrollView, imageView, mySlider;

- (IBAction) sliderValueChanged:(UISlider *)sender {
    mySlider.value = [NSString stringWithFormat:imageScrollView.[sender value]];

     //mySlider.value = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %.1f", [sender value]];


    //myTextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %.1f", [sender value]];
}


- (void)loadView {
    [super loadView];

    // set the tag for the image view
    [imageView setTag:ZOOM_VIEW_TAG];

    // add gesture recognizers to the image view
    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDoubleTap:)];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *twoFingerTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTwoFingerTap:)];

    [doubleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];
    [twoFingerTap setNumberOfTouchesRequired:2];

    [imageView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
    [imageView addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];
    [imageView addGestureRecognizer:twoFingerTap];

    [singleTap release];
    [doubleTap release];
    [twoFingerTap release];

    // calculate minimum scale to perfectly fit image width, and begin at that scale
    float minimumScale = [imageScrollView frame].size.width  / [imageView frame].size.width;
    [imageScrollView setMinimumZoomScale:minimumScale];
    [imageScrollView setZoomScale:minimumScale];
}


- (void)viewDidUnload {
    self.imageScrollView = nil;
    self.imageView = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [imageScrollView release];
    [imageView release];
    [super dealloc];
}

#pragma mark UIScrollViewDelegate methods

- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    return [imageScrollView viewWithTag:ZOOM_VIEW_TAG];
}

/************************************** NOTE **************************************/
/* The following delegate method works around a known bug in zoomToRect:animated: */
/* In the next release after 3.0 this workaround will no longer be necessary      */
/**********************************************************************************/
- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(float)scale {
    [scrollView setZoomScale:scale+0.01 animated:NO];
    [scrollView setZoomScale:scale animated:NO];
}

#pragma mark TapDetectingImageViewDelegate methods

- (void)handleSingleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    // single tap does nothing for now
}

- (void)handleDoubleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    // double tap zooms in
    float newScale = [imageScrollView zoomScale] * ZOOM_STEP;
    CGRect zoomRect = [self zoomRectForScale:newScale withCenter:[gestureRecognizer locationInView:gestureRecognizer.view]];
    [imageScrollView zoomToRect:zoomRect animated:YES];
}

- (void)handleTwoFingerTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    // two-finger tap zooms out
    float newScale = [imageScrollView zoomScale] / ZOOM_STEP;
    CGRect zoomRect = [self zoomRectForScale:newScale withCenter:[gestureRecognizer locationInView:gestureRecognizer.view]];
    [imageScrollView zoomToRect:zoomRect animated:YES];
}

#pragma mark Utility methods

- (CGRect)zoomRectForScale:(float)scale withCenter:(CGPoint)center {

    CGRect zoomRect;

    // the zoom rect is in the content view's coordinates. 
    //    At a zoom scale of 1.0, it would be the size of the imageScrollView's bounds.
    //    As the zoom scale decreases, so more content is visible, the size of the rect grows.
    zoomRect.size.height = [imageScrollView frame].size.height / scale;
    zoomRect.size.width  = [imageScrollView frame].size.width  / scale;

    // choose an origin so as to get the right center.
    zoomRect.origin.x    = center.x - (zoomRect.size.width  / 2.0);
    zoomRect.origin.y    = center.y - (zoomRect.size.height / 2.0);

    return zoomRect;
}

@end
```

Comment: Format your code and tell us what it does and what it should do.

Comment: sir i want to zoom image when slider is to be slide .
 i have implemented this method but not working plz suggest me .
- (IBAction) sliderValueChanged:(UISlider *)sender 

method is ca

Comment: Did you try `    [imageScrollView setZoomScale:sender.value];` ?

Comment: thanks mr. wain to your fast reply . 

i have used [imageScrollView setZoomScale:sender.value];

but sir my slider is also zooming with image and slider goes to out side of the user screen . i want to fix it and should not zoom with image when we use slider only image will be zoom . 

Thanks For Suggetion .

Comment: So your slider shouldn't be a subview of the scroll view.

Comment: ok sir i understand . but when i remove from sub view of scrollview its going to behind to image and image and scroll bar covers it so slider is unvisible on user screen . 

so pls give idea for slider on .xib .

Comment: You can bring the slider subview to the front (it has to be a subview of the same view as the scroll view).

Comment: your comments are really heaplfull . but when i use slider it zooms to maximum zoom scale and i want to use slider to zoom image slowly . show that should be at the place of
 [imageScrollView setZoomScale:sender.value];

Comment: change the min and max values of your slider to be the same as the min and max zoom scales.

Comment: sir the max and min values for scale not defined parmanently . it change automaticly accordingly tap on screen so how can i set these values in .xib for min and max values for slider ????

Comment: You can't, do it in code when you update the scroll view.

Comment: Thanks mr. wain my code is working .  thanks again for your valuable help ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 things to do:

1. Configure the slider so that its min and max values are equal to the min and max zoom scale of your scroll view
2. Use `[imageScrollView setZoomScale:sender.value];` to update the zoom when the slider is changed

Also, check the superview that your slider is added to. It shouldn't be added to the scroll view, it should be added to another view (possibly the scroll views superview, possibly also brought to the front).